# Calling methods on an instance without prefixing the method with the instance name for each call

Tags: ruby

## Is there a way to call multiple methods on the same instance without having to prefix each method call with the instance?

```
logger = Logger.new(STDERR)
table_name = ENV['ec2_information'].split('/')[1]

discovery = Ec2_ddb_discovery.new(logger:, table:)
discovery.scan_ddb_table
discovery.collect_stale_items.each { |item|
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "calling a class"? You cannot call classes in Ruby, you can only call methods. (Technically, you can only send messages, and the runtime system then may or may not call a method for you.)

Comment: I apologize if my question was unclear, is there a way to use scan_ddb_table and collect_stale_items methods from the discovery object without having to put 'discovery.' first

Comment: You can call `scan_ddb_table` without `discovery` (or other name of object) only in your class `Ec2_ddb_discovery`

Comment: what about [instance_exec](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_exec)?

Answer (score 1):

As max pleaner mentions in his comment, you can use [instance_eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) or if you need to pass arguments, you can use [instance_exec](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec).
These are typically used to create [DSLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), but can be us like this as well.

```
class Foo 
    def bar_one
        puts "hello from bar_one"
    end
    def bar_two
        puts "hello from bar_two"
    end
    def bar_three(arg)
        puts "hello from bar_three with #{arg}"
    end
end

Foo.new.instance_eval do  
    bar_one
    bar_two
    bar_three("local_argument")
end

Foo.new.instance_exec("passed_argument") do |arg| 
    bar_one
    bar_two
    bar_three(arg)
end
```